# doxygen error state 21 with fortran code

Tags: fortran, doxygen, fortran77

I was searching the web for help and didn't find any. Thats why I thought it might be a good idea to document my problem here.

I had the following problem while documenting a really old (15-20 years) FORTRAN-Code with doxygen. I have a file with the same filename as the subroutine in it. And some of these files gave me an error:

```
********************************************************************
Error in file FILENAME line: XX, state: 21
********************************************************************
```

I didn't figure out, what the error state 21 is. After some digging into the code I did find the problem. I have a WRITE-command like

```
       WRITE(*,'('' THIS IS SOME TEXT ''
 +     '' THIS IS SOME MORE TEXT : '',I6,
 +     /'' AND EVEN MORE TEXT ! '')')
 +     VARIABLE
```

The problem here is the exclamation mark (**!**) in the code line. Doxygen seems to interpret the end of the line after the exclamation mark as doxygen syntax and not FORTRAN code. I changed the line into

```
       WRITE(*,'('' THIS IS SOME TEXT ''
 +     '' THIS IS SOME MORE TEXT : '',I6,
 +     /'' AND EVEN MORE TEXT ! ''
 +     )')VARIABLE
```

and now everything works fine!

Comment: Does Doxygen claim to support fixed format?

Comment: @holger state 21 means and error in a string. Can you file a bug report in bugzilla?

Comment: @vladimir doxygen tries to support fixed and free formatted Fortran code

Comment: @georg / is carriage return

Comment: @albert thanks! Learned some thing new...

Comment: @albert I did [submit the bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700381)